# Sorting a list in C# (with various parameters)

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a list of objects. That objects have various field, e.g. age and name

Now sometimes I'd like to sort the list by names and sometimes by age. Additional sometimes increasing order and sometimes decreasing order.

Now I understand that i should implement the Comparable interface in my object and override the CompareTo method.

But how can i do this when i want to support various sorting orders?

Do i have to set the sorting order in my object or is it somehow possible to pass the sorting order by the sort method call?

Comment: If you are using .net 3.5 and up why not use LINQ?

Comment: LINQ would also be ok :D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The method call can do everything; no need for a comparer:

```
list.Sort((x,y)=>string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name));

list.Sort((x,y)=>y.Age.CompareTo(x.Age)); // desc
list.Sort((x,y)=>x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age)); // asc
```

Note the second is descending, by swapping x/y in the compare.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using `List<T>` and you want to sort the list *in place*, then the `Sort` function provides an overload that accepts a `Comparison<T>`. You can use this to provide different comparisons for a list.

For example, to sort on `Age`:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
```

To sort on `Name`:

```
list.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

To sort in descending order, simply reverse the parameters.

Alternatively, you could use LINQ to create various *queries* against your list that provide the results in whatever order you like, but this won't have any effect upon the underlying list (whether that's bad or good is up to you):

```
var byAge = list.OrderBy(x => x.Age);
var byName = list.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

To sort in descending order, use `OrderByDescending` in place of `OrderBy`.

Comment: Just an additional note: Sort differs from OrderBy because is [not-stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)

Comment: @digEmAll: That's correct; `Enumerable.OrderBy` is stable, `Array.Sort` (which is what `List<T>.Sort` uses) is unstable, since it's QuickSort.

Answer (score 5):

You can also just use LINQ to handle this:

```
var sortedByAge = myList.OrderBy(i => i.Age);
var sortedByName = myList.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
```

If you want to handle sorting in place, you can use [`List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
// Sort by Age
myList.Sort( (l, r) => l.Age.CompareTo(r.Age) );
// Sort by Name
myList.Sort( (l, r) => l.Name.CompareTo(r.Name) );
```

Comment: This is increasing order? and <= would be decreasing?

Comment: @Rofl, no, that's an operator that has nothing to do with ordering. These LINQ methods will be ascending. To go descending, utilize `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: If using this method, you may also need to tack ".ToList()" at the end, to get an actual list back, rather than an IEnumerable.

Comment: No, "=>" is the lamdba operator. Calling "Reverse" would do it.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: No - => allows you to define a lambda, which is a short, concise way to make a delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your objects data with linq

something like this

```
var query = from cust in customers
            orderby cust.Age ascending
            select cust;
```

Comment: Eliminate the `where` portion for the purpose of this example. For one, if you're already limiting the age to a single value, ordering on age isn't going to do anything. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Age);
```

or

```
list.OrderByAscending(a => a.Age);
```

Comment: Ok, I see you can if you use LINQ.