# How to reverse the index in array of dictionaries?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary, indexing

My array dictionary key value pairs are similar to this

```
[0] 
key : x
value : 1
[1] 
key : y
value : 2
[2] 
key : z
value : 3
```

But I need to reverse the index of the dictionary. I need to convert the above dictionary to this :

```
[0] 
key : z
value : 3
[1]
key : y
value : 2
[2] 
key : x
value : 1
```

I tried Reverse() function. But it didn't work. I don't know how to achieve this. Can anyone help me with this ?

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: array of dictionaries ?? how have you defined it, could you post some related code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting a list in C# (with various parameters)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971601/sorting-a-list-in-c-sharp-with-various-parameters)

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: If you have multiple dictionaries in an array, why has every dictionary only one item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't assume dictionaries are ordered. They aren't.

If you want to have an array that is ordered, you should use a [`SortedDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also reverse the order in there if you want to. You should use a custom comparer for that (altered from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7816014/993547)):

```
class DescendedStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        int ascendingResult = Comparer<string>.Default.Compare(x, y);

        // turn the result around
        return 0 - ascendingResult;
    }
}

//

SortedDictionary<string, string> test
     = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(new DescendedDateComparer());
```

You can iterate over it with `foreach` for example. The results will be ordered descending.

Answer (score 2):

the function Enumerable.Reverse() returns an IEnumerable not an array. Did you forget to make the reversed sequence an array? The following worked for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("x", 1);
        dict.Add("y", 2);
        dict.Add("z", 3);
        var reversed = dict.ToArray().Reverse();
        var reversedArray = reversed.ToArray();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thing he want to use order by as well.

Comment: He uses a `Dictionary<string,int>[]`

Comment: Tim: an array of dictionaries? And each dictionary contains one element? Could be, but even then, the Reverse still works.

Comment: Silent Tremor: he said he wanted a reverse of his array after he converted the dictionary to the array. The order by should be done before the ToArray(). In that case Reverse().ToArray() still returns the reverse of his array

Answer (score 1):

I tried `reverse` method, it worked. Please see below images. I used VS 2013, .Net 4.5

[image]

Output generated

[image]

Comment: You can't trust the order of a `Dictionary` the collection is unordered. It keeps the order in this toy example but as soon as you start removing and overwriting items you loose the order.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SortedDictionary and pass a key on construction

```
public sealed class CompareReverse<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> original;

    public CompareReverse(IComparer<T> original)
    {

       this.original = original;
    }

   public int Compare(T left, T right)
   {
       return original.Compare(right, left);
   }
}
```

and in your main call

```
 var mydictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(
   new CompareReverse<int>(Comparer<int>.Default));
```

for eg:-

```
  var mydictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(
   new CompareReverse<int>(Comparer<int>.Default));
  dictionary.add(1, "1");
  dictionary.add(2, "2");
  dictionary.add(3, "3");
  dictionary.add(4, "4");
```

Answer (score 0):

SortedDictionary sorts by key, not by value.

Here's a clean way to reverse the order of values in a Dictionary:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> srcList = aDictionary.ToList();

srcList.Sort(
    delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> firstPair,
    KeyValuePair<string, string> nextPair)
    {
        return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
);

Dictionary<string, string> outputDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
int listCount = srcList.Count;
for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {
    int valueIndex = i + 1;
    outputDictionary.Add(srcList[i].Key, srcList[valueIndex]);
}
```

If what you want as output is a List of KeyValuePairs rather than a Dictionary, you can replace the final 6 lines of code in my example with this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> destList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
int listCount = srcList.Count;
for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {
    int valueIndex = i + 1;
    destList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(srcList[i].Key, srcList[valueIndex]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
for (var i = dictionary.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     dictionary.Values.ElementAt(i), dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(i);
```

EDIT : Go here -> [how to iterate a dictionary<string,string> in reverse order(from last to first) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173390/how-to-iterate-a-dictionarystring-string-in-reverse-orderfrom-last-to-first)